# How does one create a cube with Julia and Makie?

Tags: julia, makie.jl

The following [Julia](https://julialang.org) program uses [Makie](https://docs.makie.org/stable) to create the image shown below, a "cube with holes."  However, I would like to **eliminate the holes**, and also **make the cube nearer the shape of an actual cube, with only *slightly* rounded corners and edges**.  I've tried changing the exponent to values other than `^2` and also passing the `range` directly to the `volume!` function, to no avail.  Examples of the types of cubes desired can be found in `three-rounded-box` images at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/three-rounded-box).

---

```
using Makie, GLMakie
fig = Figure()
range = LinRange(-1, 1, 100) # 100-element LinRange{Float64, Int64}
cube = [ (x.^2 + y.^2 + z.^2) for x = range, y = range, z = range ] # 100×100×100 Array{Float64, 3}
ax = Axis3( fig[1,1], aspect = :data, azimuth = 1.17 * pi, viewmode = :fit, title = "Cube" )
volume!( cube, algorithm = :iso, isorange = 0.05, isovalue = 1.7 )
fig
```

---

[image: A Cube with Holes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this?

```
using Makie, GLMakie
fig = Figure()
range = LinRange(-1, 1, 100) # 100-element LinRange{Float64, Int64}
cube = [ (abs.(x).^10 + abs.(y).^10 + abs.(z).^10) for x = range, y = range, z = range ] # 100×100×100 Array{Float64, 3}
ax = Axis3( fig[1,1], aspect = :data, azimuth = 1.17 * pi, viewmode = :fit, title = "Cube" )
volume!( cube, algorithm = :iso, isorange = 0.05, isovalue = 1 )
fig
```

[image]

Or you can use a parametric surface, a [supershape](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/supershape/):

```
using Makie, GLMakie

function r(phi; a, b, m, n1, n2, n3)
    return 1 / (abs(cos(m*phi/4)/a)^n2 + (abs(sin(m*phi/4)/b)^n3))^(1/n1) 
end

phi = (-pi/2):0.01:(pi/2)
theta = (-pi):0.01:(pi)
x = [
    r(theta; a=1, b=1, m=4, n1=10, n2=10, n3=10) * cos(theta) *
    r(phi;   a=1, b=1, m=4, n1=10, n2=10, n3=10) * cos(phi) 
    for phi in phi, theta in theta
]
y = [
    r(theta; a=1, b=1, m=4, n1=10, n2=10, n3=10) * sin(theta) *
    r(phi;   a=1, b=1, m=4, n1=10, n2=10, n3=10) * cos(phi) 
    for phi in phi, theta in theta
]
z = [
    r(phi;   a=1, b=1, m=4, n1=10, n2=10, n3=10) * sin(phi) 
    for phi in phi, theta in theta
]
fig, _ = surface(x, y, z)
fig
```

[image]

Better to use a function:

```
function r(phi; a, b, m, n1, n2, n3)
    return 1 / (abs(cos(m*phi/4)/a)^n2 + (abs(sin(m*phi/4)/b)^n3))^(1/n1) 
end

function supershape(p1, p2)
    phi = (-pi/2):0.01:(pi/2)
    theta = (-pi):0.01:(pi)
    x = [
        r(theta; a=p1.a, b=p1.b, m=p1.m, n1=p1.n1, n2=p1.n2, n3=p1.n3) * cos(theta) *
        r(phi;   a=p2.a, b=p2.b, m=p2.m, n1=p2.n1, n2=p2.n2, n3=p2.n3) * cos(phi) 
        for phi in phi, theta in theta
    ]
    y = [
        r(theta; a=p1.a, b=p1.b, m=p1.m, n1=p1.n1, n2=p1.n2, n3=p1.n3) * sin(theta) *
        r(phi;   a=p2.a, b=p2.b, m=p2.m, n1=p2.n1, n2=p2.n2, n3=p2.n3) * cos(phi) 
        for phi in phi, theta in theta
    ]
    z = [
        r(phi;   a=p2.a, b=p2.b, m=p2.m, n1=p2.n1, n2=p2.n2, n3=p2.n3) * sin(phi) 
        for phi in phi, theta in theta
    ]
    return (x = x, y = y, z = z)
end

params1 = (a=1, b=1, m=4, n1=10, n2=10, n3=10)
params2 = params1
x, y, z = supershape(params1, params2)

fig, _ = surface(x, y, z)
```

---

## EDIT

The rendering is not nice with `surface`. It's better to do a mesh:

```
function parametricMesh(f, umin, umax, vmin, vmax, nu, nv)
    u_ = LinRange(umin, umax, nu)
    v_ = LinRange(vmin, vmax, nv)
    vertices = Array{Float64}(undef, nu*nv, 3)
    triangles = Array{Int64}(undef, 2*(nu-1)*(nv-1), 3)
    k = 1
    for i in 1:nv
        v = v_[i]
        for j in 1:nu
            vertices[k,:] = f(u_[j], v)
            k = k+1
        end
    end
    k = 1
    for i in 1:(nv-1)
        for j in 1:(nu-1)
            a = (i-1) * nu + j
            b = (i-1) * nu + j + 1
            c = i*nu + j + 1
            d = i*nu + j
            triangles[2*(k-1)+1,:] = [b, a, d]
            triangles[2*k,:] = [c, b, d]
            k = k+1
        end
    end
    return (vertices = vertices, triangles = triangles)
end

function r(phi; a, b, m, n1, n2, n3)
    return 1 / (abs(cos(m*phi/4)/a)^n2 + (abs(sin(m*phi/4)/b)^n3))^(1/n1) 
end

p1 = (a=1, b=1, m=4, n1=10, n2=10, n3=10)
p2 = p1

function f(phi, theta)
    x = r(theta; a=p1.a, b=p1.b, m=p1.m, n1=p1.n1, n2=p1.n2, n3=p1.n3) * cos(theta) *
        r(phi;   a=p2.a, b=p2.b, m=p2.m, n1=p2.n1, n2=p2.n2, n3=p2.n3) * cos(phi)
    y = r(theta; a=p1.a, b=p1.b, m=p1.m, n1=p1.n1, n2=p1.n2, n3=p1.n3) * sin(theta) *
        r(phi;   a=p2.a, b=p2.b, m=p2.m, n1=p2.n1, n2=p2.n2, n3=p2.n3) * cos(phi)
    z = r(phi;   a=p2.a, b=p2.b, m=p2.m, n1=p2.n1, n2=p2.n2, n3=p2.n3) * sin(phi)
    return [x, y, z]
end

vertices, triangles = parametricMesh(f, -pi/2, pi/2, -pi, pi, 50, 50)

mesh(vertices, triangles, color = "yellow")
```

[image]

Comment: Someone also mentioned to me the [super-Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#Higher-order_Gaussian_or_super-Gaussian_function).